# missing ';' before 'using'

Tags: c++

I'm getting this compilation error with the following code:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'using'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "s.h"

using namespace std;
```

How is this possible? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Maybe a problem with `s.h`? Can you post that too?

Comment: The error message says it: there is a missing ';' before using. Obviously, it is missing in "s.h". You can insert the whole file instead of the #include directive to understand.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`"s.h"` might contain a class declaration that wasn't terminated with a `;`

When you include a header, the C preprocessor puts substitutes header's contents in in-line, so if you look at `s.h` you will probably find something unterminated by `;`

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your `s.h`. In C++, `#include` is only a text insertion mechanism, so if the end of a header file contains an error, you might get the error in a file that `#include`s the faulty file.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that the s.h isn't a C++ header but a C header which is not declared extern C try to replace your

```
#include "s.h"
```

with

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
#include "s.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

you could also fix this in the header file itself.